# Dice simulation finding the right dots

Tags: java

> how many dice dots do u want?
>     6
>   try 1 : 2
>   try 2 : 4
>   try 3 : 5
>   try 4 : 6
>   In 4 try's u found 6 dots

So this is what I'm trying to get as output, but can't seem to find how.

```
System.out.println("how many dice dots do u want?");
int dots = s.nextInt();
int dots2 = (int) (6 * Math.random()) + 1;
```

This is what I have. I tried a for loop now, but it doesn't seem to work. Can someone help me?

Comment: Where's your while loop? You haven't really made any attempt.. Why didn't you go on?

Comment: i didn't put my attempts in here because they dont work in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want this way:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int randomValue = 0;   //this is the random value that'd be autogenerated in each loop
    int counter = 1;    //this represents the number of trials

    System.out.println("how many dice dots do u want?");
    int dotsWanted = scan.nextInt();

    while(randomValue != dotsWanted){
        randomValue = (int) (6 * Math.random()) + 1;
        counter++;
    }

    System.out.printf("In %d trials, %d dots were found\n", counter, dotsWanted);
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score 1):

Please, format your question properly next time, it helps us to help you :)

You need a while loop to throw the dice.

```
int dots = s.nextInt();
boolean found = false;
Random rnd = new Random();
while(!found) {
   int rolled= rnd.nextInt(6) + 1;
   if(rolled == dots) // do your stuff
        found = true;
}
```

Hope it helps.